# Resharper Auto Property implement without method bodies

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

I'm using the latest ReSharper - 9. I also have StyleCop installed as well.

When I implement an interface with properties it does this:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
     public bool MyProperty
     {
         get
         {

         }
         set
         {

         }
     }
}
```

I want it to implement like this:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Exactly how do I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar thing happen on Resharper 9, and I found [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-428725) related bug in the Resharper issue tracker. Installing the update fixed it for me. Also you could try the Alt + Insert workaround as mentioned on that bug.

Comment: I should clarify that currently I am using Resharper 9.1 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you tell ReSharper to 'Implement Missing Members', there's a dropdown in the form that appears called 'Properties As:'. If you set this to Automatic property, it will generate properties in the manner you want them to. It looks like you currently have it set to 'Property with backing field'.

1. Create an interface with a property
2. Create a class to implement that interface
3. Move your cursor onto the class declaration line
4. Press Alt + Enter, and choose 'Implement Missing Members'
5. On the form that appears, set 'Properties As:' to 'Automatic property'
6. Press 'Finish'
7. Bask in your single line Auto Properties.

Comment: I can't find where to set that property

Comment: I've added step by step instructions

Comment: My resharper isn't giving me the form ... god dammit!

Comment: In that case, go to Options -> Code Editing -> Members Generation -> Create property from usage style: and set it to Automatic Property

Comment: In that case I'm out of suggestions, good luck finding a solution!

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty stuffed!

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the setting from the screenshot

[image]

Comment: @CallumLinington Maybe try to restore default configuration. Are you using official version or EAP?

Comment: I tried, "Apply Scheme" but have a feeling that doesn't include the code completion stuff. I'm using the official version - I think

Comment: @CallumLinington It only resets key shortcuts. Try that: Go to Resharper -> Manage ptions...
Click the "Reset All Settings" button.